# Adicionar um subenpoint no myaccount woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

eu estou criando uma pagina para o menu myaccount do woocommerce, e percebi a necessidade de adicionar um `sub endpoint` e não sei como fazer, alguém tem alguma ideia? Tentei

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('multiple-address', EP_PAGES);
add_rewrite_endpoint('multiple-address/form-address', EP_PAGES);
```

e não obtive sucesso

Comment: Lukan, tenta inverter, colocar o subendpoint antes.

Comment: @cbonomini inverti e funcionou! Muito obrigado !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registrando como resposta, para que fique mais claro. Para funcionar, adicionar o endpoint mais específico antes.

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('multiple-address/form-address', EP_PAGES);
add_rewrite_endpoint('multiple-address', EP_PAGES);
```